# Error: Cannot encode type ([object Object]) to a Firestore Value getting exception in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When we are inserting **geopoint** dataType document in **firestore** by using this instance

```
new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude,longitude)
```

I am getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried parsing it? JSON.parse()

Comment: Yes I have used **JSON.parse()** but when I am parsing this object it throws unexpected identifier token 'e' error.

Answer (score 0):

Latitude and Longitude parameters only accept only `number` values like

```
latitude = -37.82629;
```

It looks like you passed an object `_lat : -37.82629` which is giving an error.

check the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint)

Comment: Actually I am using **new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude,longitude)** instance to convert latitude and longitude in **geopoint** dataType for inserting geopoint data into firestore. when I am exporting data from firestore its shows same geopoint object which is in this link.  
[link](https://ibb.co/gT3z2b)